# Determine if element property is using % percentage units

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a small framework-ish thing that can make a fixed design fluid.
So as the window resizes despite the resolution the content fits.

I've had good success converting computed units between px,em & pt. But in most cases getComputedStyle returns the px value of an element conformed to percentages.

How can I obtain the percentage unit defined "by" the CSS efficiently?
(Thinking ahead I'll need to differentiate between font % and the box model %).

(Please no lodash or jQuery answers,needs to be pure JS)

Answer (score 0):

If the element's (or one of its parents) `display` is set to `none` you can get % value using javascript (if assigned in %.) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddovaxzt/2/)

```js
function getStyle(el, property) {
  var a = document.getElementById(el);
  a.style.display = "none";
  if (a.currentStyle)
    var b = a.currentStyle[property];
  else if (window.getComputedStyle)
    var b = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(a, null)
            .getPropertyValue(property);
  a.style.display = "block";
  return b;
}
console.log(getStyle('a', 'width'));
```

```css
#a {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">jdghjfgdshf</div>
```

Comment: Not sure this will be consistent between browsers, I'm supporting IE6+ and it's kind of a framework I wouldn't want to advise ppl set display to none on every element using %.

Comment: @Undefined Okay. I thought this might help. btw people dont have to set `display:none;`. I've made a change.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, maybe I should be more specific. The script is basically changing the font-size, line-height, margin & possibly  padding every time the window is resized. I think changing the display value for lets say 200 + nodes is a little too much. The margin values are split into arrays within an array, I'm also using getComputedStyle so I need to be efficient.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand. I'm building a framework I'm not making a website. It's currently working without the requirement of selectors or in-line styles and I don't want to make people use classes just to obtain the percentage.

Comment: Note that `document.defaultView` is `window`. So you can directly use `b = getComputedStyle(a, null)`. Or `b = getComputedStyle(a)` on new browsers.

Comment: I'm sure you have good reasons for supporting IE6, but for the life of me I can't imagine what they might be.